# Ember.js: Reloading a .hasMany relationship given through "links" in payload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Say I have two models, `Topic` and `Post`:

```
App.Topic = DS.Model.extend({
  posts: DS.hasMany('post', { async: true, inverse: 'post' });
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  topic: DS.belongsTo('topic', { async: true });
});
```

Topic `hasMany` Posts, and a Post `belongsTo` a Topic.

To load the data from the API, one initial call is made (which fetches a topic... topic ID 2 for example):
`GET /topics/2`

After receiving the payload for this GET request, the serializer then appends a `links` key to the payload.  This has the route to load the Posts associated with the topic:

```
"topic": {
   "id": 2,
   "links": {
      "posts": "/topics/2/posts"
   }
}
```

This second request (to `/topics/2/posts`) is how the Posts are loaded and attached to the topic.

This all works fine when the page is first loaded.

**The problem occurs when a Post is created during a page session**.  While I can get the topic itself to reload (by calling `.reload()` on the model object that represents the topic), the `Posts` associated with the topic are **not** reloaded.  The second API call (to get the posts) is never even made, while the first call (to get just the topic) *is* made.  If I refresh the page, the posts I created on the previous page load will load (but of course, if I then go and make some more posts, they won't show up until the next page load).

Looking for a solution, I came across this question:
[How to reload an async with links hasMany relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983483/how-to-reload-an-async-with-links-hasmany-relationship)

However, it appears that the solution no longer works for the current versions of Ember/Ember-Data.  The JSFiddle provided does not function.

So, **how can I reload this sort of hasMany relationship?**  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @mike, I fixed the broken fiddle, please give a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Gqf/)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of my previous question right ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reload an async with links hasMany relationship?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983483/how-to-reload-an-async-with-links-hasmany-relationship)

Comment: check the related github issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2002

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983483/how-to-reload-an-async-with-links-hasmany-relationship
Contains answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

```
DS.Model.reopen({
  reloadLink: function (linkKey) {
    if ($.isArray(linkKey)) {
      var promises = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < linkKey.length; i++) {
        promises.push(this.reloadLink(linkKey[i]));
      }
      return Em.RSVP.all(promises);
    } else {
      var rel = this._relationships[linkKey];
      if (rel) {
        if (rel.reload) {
          return rel.reload();
        } else if (rel.fetchLink) {
          return rel.fetchLink();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Example:

```
model: function () {
    var model = this.modelFor('_some_model_');
    return model.reloadLink(['link1', 'link2']).then(function () {
      return model;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there is an issue on GitHub that is not closed yet (As of today): https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1913

I do not know how to make it reload, but I thought that I will share the workaround that I did to resolve this issue.

I am using websockets, so when ever a new post is being created, I just send it through websocket and use the data to update the collection.

I am aware that this does not fix the issue with Ember Reload, but I guess this is a decent solution to the people who are already using Websockets / Socket.io.