# Reloading an async hasMany with links from server with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

It's basically this question:

[How to reload an async with links hasMany relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983483/how-to-reload-an-async-with-links-hasmany-relationship)

Where the provided solution doesn't work for me anymore using Ember 1.6.1 with Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.8.

What I get is this:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findHasMany must be an Array, not undefined
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:2966:23)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:119:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:11290:15
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10559:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10229:9)
    at publishFulfillment (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10649:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:16067:9
    at DeferredActionQueues.invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:8597:18)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:8647:15)
```

Comment: As one of the comments in that thread suggests to fix that you need to add one additional line of code. Just one line above the store.findHasMany, add: meta.type = type;

Comment: Also I think they implemented the reload on hasMany but probably it will be released with the next beta version of ember-data.

Comment: Weird, I could've sworn adding that line before did nothing. But now it does, it fixes everything. Thanks Altrim