# Ember Data async usage of hasMany

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have nested route with a hasMany relationship. I have declared the model this way:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    label: DS.attr('string'),
    archetyp: DS.attr('number'),
    searchable: DS.attr('boolean'),
    showInList: DS.attr('boolean'),
    managedItem: DS.belongsTo('managedItem')
});
```

And the corresponding model looks like so:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  logo: DS.attr('string'),
  logo_alt: DS.attr('string'),
  fields: DS.hasMany('field', {async: true})
});
```

And in the fields/index route I want to load the fields from the server. Therefore I have hooked into the model hook.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let fields = this.modelFor('managedItems/edit').get('fields');
    if (fields.get('isFulfilled')) {
      fields.reload();
    }
    return fields;
  }
});
```

But I can't see any network request and if I try to console.log(field) I see that the model is empty. What do I miss here?

EDIT: As an additional information: if I just call this.modelFor("managedItems/edit") and ask for some properties of the model object, I always get undefined except for the isLoaded property...
Here is the Router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('managedItems', {
  }, function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', {path: ':managedItem_id'});
    this.route('edit', {path: ':managedItem_id/edit' },
      function() {
           this.route('fields', { resetNamespace: true }, function () {
         });
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide some more detail.  code examples. what have you already tried? the search field "in another template".. where exactly?

Comment: I kind of fixed this issue with a store.query and retrieve the fields this way... But any help would be appreciated since I think the update of the related model won't happen this way...

Answer (score 0):

Your model hook in the route should return a Promise in any case. Have you tried something like:

```js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.modelFor('managedItems/edit').get('fields');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `managedItems/edit` to `managedItems.edit` as below:

```
let fields = this.modelFor('managedItems.edit').get('fields');
```

"*managedItems/edit*" is the path of the route (if you don't overwrite it). The name of the route is "*managedItems.edit*".

Also, `fields.reload();` is returning a promise. I'm not sure but IMO the correct model hook function will be like that:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let fields = this.modelFor('managedItems.edit').get('fields');
    if (fields.get('isFulfilled')) {
      return fields.reload(); //You should return this promise.
    }
    return fields;
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but it is not working... No request is created

Comment: Do you again get undefined for modelFor?

Comment: No, this time I get an actual class. :-) Now I need to find out how to get the related models...

Comment: What is returning from `this.modelFor('managedItems.edit').get('fields')`? A promise?

Comment: It does look this way... At least the property "isFulfilled" is set to true.

Comment: Edit: If I take a look in the console.log(fields) the isFulfilled property is set to true, but if I ask it with fields.get("isFulfilled") I get false.
But again, Ember isn't creating any requests to the server...

Comment: Any ideas why I don't get a request/data?

Comment: Nope. Maybe suggest you to have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983483/how-to-reload-an-async-with-links-hasmany-relationship)